# Why doesn't this regexp_like does not get the results I want

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-like

I'm trying the following regexp_like for a bigger query, it does not work, what am i doing wrong?

```
with xx as
  (select '333-22-234223' as a
   from dual)
select xx.a
from xx
where
  regexp_like(xx.a,'^[:digit:]{3}-[:digit:]{2}-[:digit:]{6}$');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution using `[[:digit:]]` (double `[...]`):

```
WITH xx AS (
    SELECT '333-22-234223' AS a FROM dual
)
SELECT xx.a
FROM xx
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(xx.a, '^[[:digit:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{2}\-[[:digit:]]{6}$');
```

... or using `[0-9]` instead of `[[:digit:]]`:

```
WITH xx AS (
    SELECT '333-22-234223' AS a FROM dual
)
SELECT xx.a
FROM xx
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(xx.a, '^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{6}$');
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3149e4/120/1

---

**Why does it require double brackets?**

> These character classes are valid only inside the bracketed expression.
>   **source:** https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm

Comment: Why does it require double brackets?

Comment: Because that's the syntax my friend.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm that doesn't show it here.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to @Sebastion Brosch

You can replace the character class (`[:digit:]`) with an explicit range of digits, like this:

```
with xx as
(select '333-22-234223' as a
from dual)
select xx.a
from xx
where
regexp_like(xx.a,'^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}$');
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, you can use `\d` for a digit as well:

```
with xx as
  (select '333-22-234223' as a
   from dual)
select xx.a
from xx
where regexp_like(xx.a,'^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{6}$');
```